# Python Opencv Not Working

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I have a proplem when i start running opencv with python:

this is my code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
img = cv2.imread('~/Downloads/kick.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
cv2.imshow("Image View", img)
waitkey(0)
cv2.distroyAllWindows()
```

then it shows me that error

OpenCV

```
 Error: Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) in imshow, file /build/opencv-Pg3uOK/opencv-3.2.0+dfsg/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp, line 304
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
cv2.error: /build/opencv-Pg3uOK/opencv-3.2.0+dfsg/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:304: error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function imshow
```

what is that mean

Python Version: python2.7.14 / python3.6 not running on both

Linux: Debian Jessie

Comment: Im pretty sure it can't access your image.

Comment: it means that it failed to read the image and you passed an "empty" image to the imshow.... Make sure you load it correctly and that the path is correct, try with an absolute path. Try to do print the img.shape to get an idea if it load it or not

Comment: Thank You It Works!